# Does rapid convergence of the Cesaro sums imply convergence of the original sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Question:** Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Is it true that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, if

$$\left \lvert \frac{1}{N} \left ( \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \right )\right \rvert < \frac{1}{N^{1+\varepsilon}}$$

for all $N \in \mathbb Z_+$, then $a_n$ converges to $0$?

Comment: This implies $\sum a_n$ converges (to $0$) and so $a_N = \sum_{i=0}^{N}a_n -\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}a_n$ must tend to $0$ (at rate at least $N^{-\varepsilon}$).

Comment: Ah right, this is indeed trivial as stated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $N$ to get that

$$\left \lvert   \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n \right \rvert < \frac{1}{N^{\varepsilon}}$$

Therefore $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$.